# create a program that prompts the user to enter a number between 1 and 15 and print the sum as shown: 1=1, 1+2=3, 1+2+3=6, 1+2+3+4=10

Tags: java, nested-loops

I seriously need help please 
 1=1, 1+2=3, 1+2+3=6, 1+2+3+4=10
I don't know how to code the equation part

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Equations {

public static void main(String[] args) {
   Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
   System.out.println ("Enter a number between 1 to 15: ");
   int num = scan.nextInt();
   int total = 0;
   int save;
   for(int i=1;i<=num;i++)
   {
        for(int j=1;j<=num;j++)
        {
            save = total+i;
            i++;
        }
        System.out.print (save+"="+total);
        System.out.println ();
    }
}
```

This is all I have, and it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

There are quite a few things off. You're not resetting `total` or `save` after each equation. `save` is an `int`, so it can't hold the equation string. `j` needs to increment to `i`, not `num`. `total` is never incremented. `i++` doesn't belong in the inner loop.

Here's a simple, correct version:

```
for (int i = 1; i <= num; i++) {
    int sum = 0;
    String equation = "";
    for (int j = 1; j <= i; j++) {
        sum += j;
        equation += "+" + j;
    }
    System.out.println(equation.substring(1) + "=" + sum);
}
```